# Error trying to use SDWebImage extension on UIImageView

Tags: swift, uiimage, sdwebimage

I've been going at it trying to display a user's selected profile image in a placeholder. I was successfully able to select an image but, as mentioned, it will not display in my selected placeholder.

I repeatedly receive an error stating:

> Value of type 'UIImageView' has no member 'sd_setImage'

I have written the following code.

[image: screenshot of problem]

```
class AddProfilePictureViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var userProfileImageView: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func chooseFromLibraryButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let profileImagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        profileImagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
        profileImagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
        profileImagePicker.delegate = self
        present(profileImagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
    {
        if let profileImage =
        info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage, let
        optimizedImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileImage, 0.8) {
            // Upload image from here
            uploadProfileImageData(imgageData: optimizedImageData)
        }
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController)
    {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func uploadProfileImageData(imgageData: Data)
    {
        let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView.init(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        activityIndicator.center = self.view.center

        self.view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        let storageReference = Storage.storage().reference()
        let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
        let profileImageRef = storageReference.child("users").child(currentUser!.uid).child("profileImage.jpg")

        let uploadMetaData = FirebaseStorage.StorageMetadata()
        uploadMetaData.contentType = "image/jpeg"

        profileImageRef.putData(imgageData, metadata: uploadMetaData) { (uploadedImageMeta, error) in
            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            activityIndicator.removeFromSuperview()

            if error != nil
            {
                print("Error took place \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
                return
            } else {
                print("Meta data of uploaded image \(String(describing: uploadedImageMeta))")
            }

            let storageReference = Storage.storage().reference()
            // create a reference to the file you want to download
            let profileImageDownloadUrlReference = storageReference.child("users/\(currentUser!.uid)/profileImage.jpg")

            // UIImageView in your ViewController
            // let imageView: UIImageView = self.imageView

            // Placeholder image
            let placeholderImage = UIImage(named: "placeholder.jpg")

            // Load the image using SDWebImage
            userProfileImageView.sd_setImage(with: profileImageDownloadUrlReference, placeholderImage: placeholderImage)

            // fetch the download url

            profileImageDownloadUrlReference.downloadURL { url, error in
                if let error = error {
                    // Handle any errors
                    print("Error took place \(error.localizedDescription)")
                } else {
                    // get the download URL for 'images/stars.jpg'
                    print("Profile image download URL \(String(describing: url!))")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you import sdwebimage?

Answer (score 2):

1. Add pod 'FirebaseUI/Storage' in your Podfile
2. Open terminal and pod install
3. You need to import FirebaseUI in this swift file.

```
    import UIKit
    import Firebase
    import FirebaseUI

    class SelectProposeViewController: UIViewController {
        @IBOutlet weak var ImageView: UIImageView!
        @IBOutlet weak var UserImageView: UIImageView!
        
        var proposal_dict: ProposalShow?
        let storage = Storage.storage()
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.title=""
            
            self.UserImageView.sd_setImage(with: self.storage.reference(forURL: self.proposal_dict?.proposalDict["userphoto"] as! String) , placeholderImage: UIImage())
            self.ImageView.sd_setImage(with: self.storage.reference(forURL: self.proposal_dict?.proposalDict["postphoto"] as! String))
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: please contextualize more your answer, show a code example etc

Answer (score 2):

1. Add pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 5.0' in your Podfile
2. Navigate to your project folder and type "pod install"
3. In your swift file, add "import SDWebImage"

You probably forgot to install SDWebImage library. You can check out this library here. 
https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage

Answer (score 0):

You have to import SDWebImage on top of class where you set image to your image view.
After import just build your app and error will be gone.
You can also use KingFisher pod for image loading. It is lighter than sdwebimage.

1.First create a storage reference (see Firebase doc): https://Firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files

2.Now you can load the image directly from Firebase Storage as URL no need to store any HTTP URL Firebase will internally do everything for you.

You can save a reference name of a particular image in the Firebase Database to identify that particular image.

Use this code.

```
// Reference to an image file in Firebase Storage
 let reference = storageRef.child("images/stars.jpg")

// UIImageView in your ViewController
let imageView: UIImageView = self.imageView

// Placeholder image
let placeholderImage = UIImage(named: "placeholder.jpg")

// Load the image using SDWebImage
imageView.sd_setImage(with: reference, placeholderImage: placeholderImage)
```

Comment: Yes I did that, but I still have a red highlighted error by the 'load image using SDWebImage' section which now says "Cannot convert value of type 'StorageReference' to expected argument type 'URL?'"